# How to export file in For loop?

Tags: export, files-and-directories, mathematica-online

I am using the following code to export a file with three columns. I am using the Export file command like this but not getting the output. Can someone please help with this?

```
 For[i = 0, i < 0.4, i += 0.01,
 a = i*i;
 b = 5*i + 3*i;
 c = 10*i^2 + 8*i + 10;
 Export["out.dat", a, " ", b, " ", c]
 ]
```

Comment: Did you get any error messages? Did you read the documentation for Export? But on top of those issues, what are you actually trying to achieve? If you loop multiple times and Export to the same file multiple times, are you wanting to override the file each time or append to it or what?

Comment: Any reason you are doing this line by line? Also, you'll only capture the last line as you are overwriting the file in each line.

Comment: @Edmund I want to have a file on which the first column will be a, second b and third c. I need to export this data file. How can we do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better first create a table of the lines and then print the table in one go:

```
tab = Table[
  a = i*i;
  b = 5*i + 3*i;
  c = 10*i^2 + 8*i + 10;
  ToString[StringForm["``  ``  ``", a, b, c]]
  , {i, 0, 0.399, 0.01}]
Export["filename", tab]
```